# ng-repeat not triggering when changing the collection in click function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below ng-repeat function

$scope.clientsAll is a collection which list out all the clients.

```
<div ng-repeat="client in clientsAll">
  <div class="col-sm-6 type2 adminExistingText pLeftZ">
    <span id="nameText">{{client.name}}</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]" init="terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]=client.effective_end_dt" ng-model="terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]">
  <button type="button" ng-click="cancelExistingClient($index)">change</button>
</div>
```

I am changing the collection in button click event, i.e removing the item from the collection like below

```
$scope.cancelExistingClient= function (index) {
        // Remove the user from the array instead of reloading the entire list again. If removed from list, this will remove from the UI (ng-repeat) without affecting the other accordions
        var clientFound = $filter('filter')($scope.clientsAll, { "id": index}, true)[0];
        var clientPosition = $scope.clientsAll.indexOf(clientFound);
        $scope.clientsAll.splice(clientPosition, 1);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

After changing the collection, that item gets removed from the list,but the termination date of the client is not updated to the model. i.e client.effective_end_dt  contains the value but it is not updating to terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index].I am not sure whether ng-repeat re-renders when changing the clientsAll variable.

The structure of clientsAll like below

```
  $scope.clientsAll=[{"id":1, "name":'xxx',"effective_end_dt":'2/3/2017'}]
```

When i remove the item  from the collection , I want to ensure that terminationdate  model should keep the value of client effective end date.When i refresh the page all the clients listing out the date properly.

Comment: `clientsAll` is not an array.

Comment: @DanielA I have updated the question with one item, it has multiple items with in it

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `splice` item from array using index property, i.e. you are passing `$index` in `ng-click` function which could be confusing for some cases.

Try to pass `ng-repeat` variable in `ng-click` and on basis of that variable `splice` the item from array.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  angular.module('myApp',[])
  .controller('myCtrl', function myCtrl($scope,$filter) {
   $scope.clientsAll= [{"id":1, 
   "name":'xxx',
   "effective_end_dt":'2/3/2017'
  },{"id":2, 
  "name":'yyy',
  "effective_end_dt":'8/8/2017'
 },{"id":3, 
 "name":'zzz',
 "effective_end_dt":'11/11/2017'
}];

$scope.cancelExistingClient= function (item) {
        // Remove the user from the array instead of reloading the entire list again. If removed from list, this will remove from the UI (ng-repeat) without affecting the other accordions


        angular.forEach($scope.clientsAll, function(index) {
         if (index.id == item.id) {
          var arrayIndex = $scope.clientsAll.indexOf(index);
          if (arrayIndex > -1) {
           $scope.clientsAll.splice(arrayIndex, 1);
          }
         }
        })


        // var clientFound = $filter('filter')($scope.clientsAll, { "id": index}, true)[0];
        // var clientPosition = $scope.clientsAll.indexOf(clientFound);
        // $scope.clientsAll.splice(clientPosition, 1);
        // $scope.$apply();
    }

})



</script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="client in clientsAll">
  <div class="col-sm-6 type2 adminExistingText pLeftZ">
   <span id="nameText">{{client.name}}</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]"
  init="terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]=client.effective_end_dt"
  ng-model="client.effective_end_dt">
  <button type="button" ng-click="cancelExistingClient(client)" >change</button>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks. what was the exact change you made from the code snippet provided by me

Comment: @SivaRajini I have edited my answer check that, and accept it if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
ng-click="cancelExistingClient(client)"

$scope.cancelExistingClient = function(obj){
    $scope.clientAll = $scope.clientAll.filter((client) => client.name !== obj.name);
};
```

Comment: My filter code itself is working fine. the problem is when any changes happened to clientsAll , the  model "terminationdate['terminationdate_'+$index]" value gone. that means termination date model value removed. eventhough client.effective_end_dt contains the value

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 <div ng-repeat="client in clientsAll" ng-model="$index = getCurrIndex(client)">
    <div class="col-sm-6 type2 adminExistingText pLeftZ">
    <span id="nameText">{{client.name}}</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="terminationdate[$index]"                                                                    
    ng-model="terminationdate[$index] = client.effective_end_dt">
    <button type="button" ng-click="cancelExistingClient($index)">change</button>                                                         
</div>

$scope.cancelExistingClient= function (index) {
   $scope.clientsAll.splice(index, 1);
   $scope.$apply();
}

$scope.getCurrIndex = function (client){
  return $scope.clientsAll.indexOf(client);
}
```